# Python3 multiprocessing.pool in PyQt5 QThread raises TypeError cannot pickle 'TaskThread'[QThread] object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing

I've this piece of code to try to understand use of **Python3** `multiprocessing.pool` in a **PyQt5** `QThread` :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal , pyqtSlot

import time

import os

import multiprocessing as mp


def work(x):
    # print('os.getpid() : {}'.format(os.getpid()), time.time(),'\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
    
    return x
     

class TaskThread(QThread):
    
    results = pyqtSignal(object)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        print("Thread app:", int(QThread.currentThread().currentThreadId()))
    
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        
        print('run..................')
        
        print("Thread app run :", int(QThread.currentThread().currentThreadId())) ## i.e. 140079831918336
        
        print("Thread app run :", (QThread.currentThread())) ## i.e. <__main__.TaskThread object at 0x7f66ed6f9280>
        
        print("Thread app run :", (QThread.currentThread().currentThreadId())) ## i.e. <sip.voidptr object at 0x7f66eceb94b0>
        
        testFL = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        pool = mp.Pool(6)
       
        
       
        result = pool.map(self.work, testFL)  # TypeError: cannot pickle 'TaskThread' object
        
        # result = pool.map(work, testFL)  ## this works using work at top level 
        
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        
        
        # result = []
        # for i in testFL:
            
        #     result.append(self.work(i))
            
            
        
        
        # print(result)
        # print(type(result))
        
        self.results.emit(result)
        
        print('QThread run finished')
        
    def work(self, x):
        # print('os.getpid() : {}'.format(os.getpid()), time.time())
        # time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        return x
        
        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 50)
        self.setWindowTitle('QThread Demo')
        
        # setup widget
        self.widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)       

        self.btn_start = QPushButton('Start', clicked=self.start)

        layout.addWidget(self.btn_start)
        
        print("QMainWindow:", int(QThread.currentThread().currentThreadId()))
        
    def start(self):
        
        self.use_thread()


    def use_thread(self):
        self.thread = TaskThread(self)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.task_finished)
        
        
        self.thread.results.connect(self.print_qthread_res)
        
        self.thread.start()
    
    @pyqtSlot(object)
    def print_qthread_res(self, objectz):
        
        print('passssed .......... : ', objectz)
        print('type : ', type(objectz))
    
    def task_finished(self):
        
        print('QThread FINISHED !!!!!!!!!')
        pass
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

That gives an error  :

`result = pool.map(self.work, testFL)  # TypeError: cannot pickle 'TaskThread' object .... ....   TypeError: cannot pickle 'TaskThread' object`

I can make the code work by changing:

`result = pool.map(self.work, testFL)` to `result = pool.map(work, testFL)`

using function `work` defined at the top of the script instead of the  `class TaskThread` function `work` (`self.work`).

or by defining `TaskThread.work` as:

```
    global work   
    
    def work( x):
        # print('os.getpid() : {}'.format(os.getpid()), time.time())
        # time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        return x
```

and using `result = pool.map(work, testFL)`

and of course commenting-out `work` function defined at the top of the script.

My question is why I get the error, which one of mine solutions is the better one ? Or should I be aware of something else to have my script working in the correct way ?

Comment: Where is that last example of `work` defined? Is it at global scope or is it still a method of the TaskThread class, just missing the `self` parameter? If that's the case, it should still fail - python doesn't care what you call that first parameter, if its an instance method, the first parameter is always a reference to the object instance.

Comment: this can explain your problem https://laszukdawid.com/blog/2017/12/13/multiprocessing-in-python-all-about-pickling/

Comment: @tdelaney , it is still a method of the TaskThread class, just missing the self parameter and doesnt fail with me, I see your point. Adding selfs in throws the AttributeError: 'TaskThread' object has no attribute 'work'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `self.worker` is an instance method, which means that the instance must be pickled and sent to the worker process for execution. Not all classes can be pickled, and certainly not a `TaskThread` (which would somehow have to execute a thread??). And more generally, you need to be careful about how much stuff you are pickling and sending to subprocess for performance reasons.

Defining `work` as a function instead of a method is very likely the best way to go. Decouple the parent class instance from the work being done in the subprocess as much as possible.

Its not clear what that final example using `global work` is supposed to do. `global` only makes sense within a function - its job is to tell the compiler to assign values in the global namespace, not the local function namespace. It doesn't declare a variable as global for all functions.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I'll look about pickle. The final example was got by mistake, mistake being not adding self in function args and keeping the result = pool.map(work, testFL) for the top level function ,  but was thought as a way to be able to carry the TaskThread class toghether with the function to be multiprocessed. Thats why I was asking if it was kosher. Probably I should reformulate my question in how to be able to carry the function for pool toghether with my TaskThread (i.e. if I would like to pass it from module to module) but obviusly seems not feasible